# ampscript get max value of column in dataextension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to get max date value of a dataextension by LookupOrderedRows getting first row of that rowset.

How can I get max/min date value of a dataextension with ampscript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an AMPScript only solution, you will need to put in a field into your DE that ALL rows contain.  E.g. I usually include a column labeled 'Secret' that has a value of 1 for all of my rows.

From there you will be able to do your [lookuporderedrows()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookuporderedrows/) function. As @KennethWagner has stated, there is a default limitation of around 2K records on the lookups, but if you use [DataExtensionRowCount()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/dataextensionrowcount/) on the DE you are looking up on, you can get around this limitation.  Keep in mind, this can have drastic effects if you are looking up against a significantly sized DE.

So basically, you would use the following:

```
LookupOrderedRows(@YourDE, DataExtensionRowCount(@YourDE), 'Date desc', 'Secret', 1)
```

Ref: [Sprignature moves](https://sprignaturemoves.com/category/salesforce-marketing-cloud/) from the Amazing @AdamSpriggs is a great resource for Reference on everything SFMC and for best practices.

You can also utilize [SQL Queries](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) (via Automation Studio or Interactions in Email Studio) to pull this value, using something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Date
FROM YOUR_DE
```

or you can utilize SSJS [Data Extension Retrieve](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/retrieve/) option (Note: Not for use inside of an email, only in Landing pages/Microsites/Script interaction)

```
var YourDE = DataExtension.Init('YourDE');
var results = YourDE.Retrieve({Property:"CustomerKey",SimpleOperator:"notEqual",Value:"NotValue"});
```

SSJS solution is a bit clunky and can wind up slowing things down, so unless you absolutely need it or are more comfortable in SSJS I would highly recommend SQL or the AMPScript above.